Scrapy Spider Not Finding 2 Div Elements out of Hundreds Correctly Scraped
I'm using Scrapy in Jupyternotebook to scrape the Yellowpages website and am running into a strange error.
My code scrapes the list view of YellowPages for when a user types in 'auto' for a variety of zip codes. While my code is correctly able to scrape almost all of the business listings (around 500) there are 2 that I cannot get my Spider to scrape.
These are 2 businesses: Roger's Services and Northeastern Bus Rebuilders. (See screenshot below for how they appear on the website). I've inspected the website's html and the structure of the divs containing the information I'm scrapping doesn't seem markedly different from any of the other divs that were easily scraped. The webpage I'm having issues with can be found [here](https://www.yellowpages.com/search?
search_terms=auto&geo_location_terms=02136). Note that all businesses on this page and subsequent pages are correctly scraped. Only 2, on this page specifically, seem to not be 'seen' by the Spider.
I tried scraping the information by getting a div containing the divs and elements I want by ID, but to no avail.
I've tried with css selector and with xpath. See my code below for my attempts. I was able to successfully get the results container div of the business directly above the Roger's Services using the css and xpath to access the div.results lid-XXXX element, but when I put in the Roger Services ID, I get nothing.
Any advice for why this might be happening? I'm genuinely at a loss because the html seems exactly the same between business listings and only these two seem to be causing problems.
Please let me know what you might do to solve it! Thank you!
This is my parse code, with print statements where I tried debugging:
def parse(self, response):
        
        ### DEBUGGING SECTION BEGIN ###

        div_pointer = response.css('div#lid-5671823')
        #div_pointer = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "5671823")]')
        div_content = div_pointer.get()
        if(div_content!=None):
            print('The div containing Roger Service')
            print(div_content)
            print('Trying to get the stuff inside:')
            div_inside = div_pointer.css('div.info-section.info-primary')
            print(div_inside)

        ### DEBUGGING SECTION END ###

        containing_divs = response.css('div.info-section.info-primary') # works fine for everything else 

        for containing_div in containing_divs:
            business_name = containing_div.css('a.business-name span::text').get()
            if (business_name==None):  # note, paid listings are slightly differently coded in the html, so error handling below:
                business_name = containing_div.css('a.business-name::text').get()
                href = containing_div.css('a.business-name::attr(href)').get()
                end_of_href = href[href.rfind('-')+1:] # returns ypid-?lid=....
                ypid = end_of_href[:end_of_href.rfind('?lid')]# substring to return only ypid
            else:
                href = containing_div.css('a.business-name::attr(href)').get()
                ypid = href[href.rfind('-')+1:] #the ypid is the end of the link (href), so substring the link from the last - to the end
        
            categories = containing_div.css('div.categories a::text').extract()
            
            if(ypid.rfind('?lid')!=-1): # Clean ypid, in case (some hrefs of non paid include ?... etc. at end)
                end_of_href = href[href.rfind('-')+1:] # returns ypid-?lid=....
                ypid = end_of_href[:end_of_href.rfind('?lid')]# substring to return only ypid

            yield {
               'business_name':business_name,
                'ypid':ypid,
                'categories':categories
            }




I don't understand at all what your problem is. Everything works correctly, I just followed the link provided, saved the html, passed it to the Selector class and used your code. The companies you are talking about were successfully parsed. I then tested the second option and wrote a spider that opens your link and uses your code again. That worked as well! Both of the companies you're talking about were found in two variants. To help you, please provide the html on which the parse method is run.

Hello! I actually was able to get it to run without issues by hardcoding the zipcodes earlier in the code in the request formulation part of the class. I'm not sure why this made the difference but now I get all the businesses I expected! Thank you for your help though!

I can't find the issue with your code, but you can do this easier with BeautifulSoup:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=auto&geo_location_terms=02136'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = [{
    'business_name': r.select_one('a.business-name').text, 
    'ypid': r.select_one('a.business-name').get('href').rsplit('-', 1)[-1].rsplit('?lid=', 1)[0],
    'categories': [a.text for a in r.select('div.categories > a')] 
} for r in soup.select('div.result')]

print(data)

the data is also available in a script[type="application/ld+json"], but it does not include the paid listings, or the categories:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=auto&geo_location_terms=02136'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json', string=lambda txt: 'LocalBusiness' in txt)
data = json.loads(script.text)
print(data)

and you can add the categories like so:
categories = {r.select_one('a.business-name').text: [a.text for a in r.select('div.categories > a')] for r in soup.select('div.result')}
for d in data:
    d['categories'] = categories.get(d['name'], [])


Hello! I actually was explicitly trying to avoid using beautiful soup, but I was able to get it to work somehow by changing my start requests code. I'm not sure why it solved the issue as the page they're on was being pulled but now I get all the businesses I was expecting. Thank you for your help though!

I think you can't select correctly because your approach is not general enough. Here's what I did:
    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section info-primary']")
        if rows:
            for row in rows:
                business_name = row.xpath("./descendant::a[@class='business-name']/descendant-or-self::*/text()").get()
                href = row.xpath("./descendant::a[@class='business-name']/@href").get()
                categories = row.xpath("./descendant::div[@class='categories']/a/text()").getall()
                print(business_name, href, categories)
                print("-"*100)
        else:
            # handle ... T.B.D
            pass


